# Assistance Required: Encountering 'r_JYMBII' Error with LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

#Linkedin

Hello

I am developing a personal tool that match my skills and resume to potential jobs and apply automatically to the "Easy Apply" jobs.

I am getting an error related to r_JYMBII Permission to search for jobs and separate permissions to apply for jobs.

Please help

#Linkedin

I am getting an error related to r_JYMBII Permission within the API to search for jobs and separate permissions to apply for jobs.

Please help